# How can autoprefixer work in angular with single file components?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, autoprefixer

I'm working on a project where we are creating a shared component module to be imported in various applications across the organization. We are creating components with css that allows us to have a consistent look and feel across our applications. Our organization needs to support Internet Explorer 11. We created a grid component utilizing CSS Grid for layout and styling. Everything seemed to be working well in the shared module until we pushed it to our npm feed and then pulled it into our projects. We noticed that autoprefixer seemed to stop working. When I dug a bit further, I found that it seems to be a problem with single file components vs. multi-file components. The build process for the shared libraries takes our multi-file components and makes them into single file components and doesn't put the css through autoprefixer. (The library and build were generated by @angular/cli following the example here: https://netbasal.com/create-angular-libraries-in-no-time-using-schematics-513cb1e08a5e)

---

**Multi-file Component**

If I have two files as follows:
`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div id="grid1" role="grid">
      <div role="columnheader">Column 1</div>
      <div role="columnheader">Column 2</div>

      <div role="gridcell">Row 1 Cell 1</div>
      <div role="gridcell">Row 1 Cell 2</div>

      <div role="gridcell">Row 2 Cell 1</div>
      <div role="gridcell">Row 2 Cell 2</div>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

`app.component.css`

```
#grid1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, min-content);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, min-content);
}
```

Autoprefixer correctly creates the prefixes:

```
display: -ms-grid;
display: grid;
-ms-grid-rows: (min-content)[2];
grid-template-rows: repeat(2, -webkit-min-content);
grid-template-rows: repeat(2, min-content);
-ms-grid-columns: (min-content)[2];
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, -webkit-min-content);
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, min-content);
```

---

**Single file Component**

If I have a single file as follows:
`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div id="grid1" role="grid">
      <div role="columnheader">Column 1</div>
      <div role="columnheader">Column 2</div>

      <div role="gridcell">Row 1 Cell 1</div>
      <div role="gridcell">Row 1 Cell 2</div>

      <div role="gridcell">Row 2 Cell 1</div>
      <div role="gridcell">Row 2 Cell 2</div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    #grid1 {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: repeat(2, min-content);
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, min-content);
    }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

Autoprefixer seems to be bypassed and the styles that get to the browser are:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: repeat(2, min-content);
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, min-content);
```

Is there a way to get autoprefixer to create the prefix styles for single file components?

Answer (score 1):

Until latest version of Angular (6.x), this issue hasn't been solved yet ([doc](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#non-css-style-files)). Autoprefixer can only be applied in Multi-file Component

> Style strings added to the @Component.styles array must be written in CSS because the CLI cannot apply a preprocessor to inline styles.